# How to remove glide effect in working with oscillator?

Tags: audiokit

Any can help with the problem of glide effect with using oscillator.
Here is the part of code, I need that every cycle oscillator sounds on new random frequency. But frequencies are changed smoothly with glide effect. How to remove glide effect?

for _ in 1...20 {

```
oscillator.frequency = Double.random(in: 0...10000)
oscillator.start()
sleep(1)
oscillator.stop()
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `oscillator.rampDuration`:

```
oscillator.frequency = Double.random(in: 0...10000)
oscillator.rampDuration = 0.0

oscillator.start()
sleep(1)
oscillator.stop()
```

Comment: If you command-click on the `AKOscillator` object type, you can jump to its definition to see all of its available properties.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! rampDuration works! as for command-click and definition - I tried, but received message: Couldnt generate Swift Presentation. Error (from SourceKit): Could not load module: AudioKit

Comment: By the way, maybe you can also help how to avoid amplitude click while oscillator restarts?

Comment: Recommend using the same method as in any synthesizer generally: Use an envelope to make it quieter initially. That would likely be an amplitude "for loop" with a duration between each iteration using "perform" or similar in swift. Imagine audiokit already includes a MUCH easier way to do that though.

Comment: PS: Actually came here looking for a way to add portamento to a note that is already playing so it can glide to frequency of next note. Still working on a way to do that.